# iDRAC not working at all

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, drac

I have a Dell PowerEdge R620, and I figured it could use a firmware update. I updated the BIOS (to version 2.9.0) without any problems, and then I booted off of the platform-specific ISO (version 21.09.00) which automatically updated iDRAC and the lifecycle controller (iDRAC with Lifecycle Controller v. 2.65.65.65). According to the BIOS, I'm now running the latest version of iDRAC7 (1.66.65), but iDRAC has stopped working completely.

here are the "symptoms":

- iDRAC fails to initialize

  - after failing to initialize, I'm met with "Alert! iDRAC not responding. rebooting."
  - after rebooting, it tries again (and fails), but lets me boot if I ignore a warning (requires 3 keypresses just to boot, so not ideal for a headless server
- the fans are stuck at 100%
- the system health LED doesn't turn on at all
- the iDRAC ethernet port indicator LEDs don't turn on when plugged in

I've tried reinstalling the iDRAC update, but it seems like iDRAC needs to run in order to update it. I've also tried formatting the vFlash SD card and copying firmimg.d7 (extracted from the update executable) onto it. That seems to do something, as the fans don't ramp up to 100% before it reboots, instead of going straight to 100% as soon as I power it on. It only does that during the first boot after copying the file to the SD card though.

Is there any way to fix this, or will I have to resort to replacing the motherboard? Any suggestions, ideas, or kinds of help are greatly appreciated.